# Scale images when uploading to SharePoint

Tags: file-upload, image

We are using SharePoint for our internet site and we're looking for a way / component that can help us to resize/scale images on the fly, while uploading to SharePoint. Is there something that we can use? Script / addon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've done a similar thing which was to generate various thumbnail image sizes within an event receiver; which is applied to the content type of the image.

The resizing was done using fairly simple code. If you want to go down this route, please add a comment and I'll post some snippets from the code.

Comment: Sounds good, if possible i would like to see that code.